# How I can get Verdana PostScript type1 font?

Tags: fonts, postscript

I need to use Verdana with cp1251 in my project. Where can I get you?

Answer (score 2):

Installing the **Ubuntu Restricted Extras** adds the Verdana font to, for example, LibreOffice.

Open **Software Center** and look for **Ubuntu Restricted Extras** and install that Meta package which will install other packages including the one you want (In this case `msttcorefonts`)

[image]

After install you can see it in any program that uses Fonts like LibreOffice:

[image]

Comment: That's how you get Verdana, but does it actually give you a PS Type 1 version of it?

Comment: I found that the installed fonts fall in /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts so I see that no, it is TTF instead of PS. I can search a little bit more to see if there is more to know about this.

Comment: Found this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4309/which-font-formats-can-i-use So I guess that freetype 2 can make the fonts work interchangeably. This of course you would need to test with the program you want to use and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you mean.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-microsoft-core-fonts-in-ubuntu-linux/

Hope it helps

Comment: You know, i had did it before, and now in my /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts many new fonts appeared, But which one of them is Verdana?